# Disable black screen clock / turn screen off completely in Lumia 650

Tags: lock-screen, screen, lumia-650

I have recently migrated to Lumia 650 from Lumia 635. On Lumia 635 / Windows 8.1, when I pressed power button, screen was turned off completely and I could visually confirm that it turned off and it is not showing black pixels.

When I do the same with Lumia 650 / Windows 10, when I press power button, screen turns entirely black (but it is still turned on) with dark-white letters showing current date and time. Screen turns off completely after something around 20-30 minutes or so.

This is quite very annoying to me and yet I can find any option in settings to disable this feature and to force my phone to really turn off screen immediately after I press power button. Or to reduce time phone is in this mode to an absolute minimum.

Am I blind and this option is there, somewhere? Or isn't another feature in Windows / Lumia which Microsoft thinks, I can't live without and thus disallows me from turning it off or changing its behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called **Glance Screen** Feature and it is supported on newer devices like your 650. I am astonished that you hate this feature and I miss this feature so much on my Lumia 535.

Glance Screen is a unique Windows phone feature that use to display a summarized information from notifications. All the information displayed by Glance Screen can be easily enabled or disabled with a tap on the appropriate switch.
Note that the notifications and Background app content are all information gathered by Glance Screen from your Lock Screen settings.Glance Screen also checks your front camera / lightness sensor and turns itself off when it detects complete darkness, i.e. if you put your phone upside down or hide it in your pocket. So it may cause a little battery drain but overall it is one of the best feature of Windows phones.

Well, if you don't like this feature, you can turn it off via Settings. Just type Glance Screen in search box of settings, tap it and turn it off. Glance Screen settings can also be located under the category **Personalization** Or **Extras** depending upon the OS version you're using.

For more information about Glance Screen have a look on [this article](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-use-configure-glance-screen-windows-phone-lumias).

Comment: My "hate" is not toward Glance Screen itself but about insane battery drain I could observe on all my Lumias. Thus, I'm trying to disable as much as power consuming stuff as possible. I assume that Glance Screen turned on consumes more energy even showing most of the screen black then phone consumes when its display is completely turned off (i.e. with Glance Screen disabled). BTW: I made a small edit to your answer to enhance it with information about Glance Screen auto-turn off feature. We'll see, if my edit will pass review queue.

Comment: Now it's fine @trejder I have also added a link which may help you more. Thanks for your edit. Cheers!

Comment: @trejder The Lumia 650 has an AMOLED display so any power draw from Glance Screen will be negligible. If you're still concerned, though, you can set Glance Screen to only show for a limited amount of time. I'd still recommend you give it a try, though - as this answer explains, it's a very useful feature.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion. Unfortunately (later) it turned out that Calendar (Outlook and API in general -- 3rd party apps) and Outlook are complete mistakes under Windows 10. At least in compare to Windows 8.1. Calendar is unusable at all (at least in the way I used to using it) and while Outlook synces mails and folders after a very, very long time and completely fails to fetch mails from my office account even after dozen of tries and changes to configuration. This and many more led me to a decision about returning Lumia 650 back to shop and getting something with Windows 8.1 on board.

Answer (score 2):

Settings --> Personalization --> Glance Screen --> Turn off "Show Glance Screen when the display is turned off."

There are also some other settings if you only want to have it in certain day/night times, a different color etc.

---

Disclaimer: I am using Windows 10 Mobile on the current fast ring and my language is set to German so the exact menu names might differ, but I think this option is the current Windows 10 production build too.